# C++: convert unsigned long long to unsigned long

Tags: c++, unsigned

I am trying to convert an unsigned long long to unsigned long. Is the following a correct way to do it?

```
unsigned long removeExtraBits2(unsigned long long c) {
    return (unsigned long) ((c << 32) >> 32);
}
```

If not, can you provide a working example?

My assumption is that when shifting left, and then back right, the 32 leftmost bits get set to 0.

Thanks!

EDIT: The purpose of the conversion is to get rid of the extra bits, 'higher' than the 32nd, effectively keeping only the rightmost 32 bits into an unsigned long.

Comment: `static_cast<unsigned long>(c);` not good enough?  Why are you writing a function?

Comment: Where are you getting "32" from? What if `unsigned long` has 64 bits? Or 49? Or 111?

Comment: Because it doesn't seem to work. I have the `unsigned long long c = 39134856588429`; when doing `unsigned long converted = (unsigned long) c;`, I get 3409554573 which clearly is not correct

Comment: @Dimebag, [Why not](https://www.google.ca/search?sourceid=chrome-psyapi2&rlz=1C1CHFX_enCA628CA628&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8&q=39134856588429%20mod%202%5E32&oq=39134856588429%20mod%202%5E32&aqs=chrome..69i57j0.6523j0j7)? Or if you'd prefer [masking](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=39134856588429+%26+0xFFFFFFFF)...

Comment: Ouch, you're right. Now this is embarrassing... Too much coding, can't even think properly

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just do a "plain" cast (`(unsigned long)c`, or, if you like verbosity, `static_cast<unsigned long>(c)`, or even just assign the `unsigned long long` source value to the `unsigned long` target variable), the standard guarantees that the extra bits on the left will get truncated.

> If the destination type is unsigned, the resulting value is the least unsigned integer congruent to the source integer (modulo 2<sup>n</sup> where n is the number of bits used to represent the unsigned type).

(C++11, §4.7 ¶2)

which, if the source is unsigned (or is signed and in 2's complement arithmetic), is a fancy way to say that the extra bits are truncated.

Comment: I don't think there is such a thing as unsigned overflow. It just dictates the value, not overflow: *If the destination type is unsigned, the resulting value is the least unsigned integer congruent to the sourceinteger (modulo 2ⁿ where n is the number of bits used to represent the unsigned type)* Of course it's still the same answer.

Comment: But, if you need to ditch all but the low 32-bit bits, don't use `unsigned long`, use `uint32_t`.

Comment: @chris: you are right, I don't know what I was remembering; there's even a note that says "This implies that unsigned arithmetic does not overflow".

Answer (score 0):

There are many different processors and operating systems. The `unsigned long long` is 64-bits almost on everything. The `unsigned long` is the other story. It is for example **64**-bits on Linux x86-64, **32**-bits on Linux x86-32 and **32**-bits on Windows x86-64 and x86-32. Plain convert may be noop.

I think this is a safe solution.

```
unsigned long removeExtraBits(unsigned long long c) {
    c %= 0x100000000ULL;
    return (unsigned long)(c);
}
```

Compiler will change `%` to simple `mov`.